# Can someone help me identify what the part number of the pink connector is? It's for the DC power jack harness on a nordictrack elliptical

Tags: power, dc, connector

I salvaged an elliptical machine from the dump, and the only issue it has is a broken barrel jack power harness (please see [this link for a picture of the harness I want to build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TXMJMB8)) -- this part costs something like $70.00 CAD (not including customs) by the time it's shipped.

I went on digikey and [found the 32T barrel jack](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/schurter-inc/4840-2200/1212406) for one end of the harness, for  approximately $2.36! On the other end, there is the pink three position connector. I don't know what type of connector that is, but it's not an XHR connector. Does anyone know what manufacturer / part number that connector is?

As requested, I've posted some pictures and found the pitch between pins. The pitch is .1 " / 2.54mm between the pins.

Here are the better quality image links:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: From _that_ picture? No way! Post pictures of the connector you have on your hands and of the mate that it plugs into. Measure the [pitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=connector+pitch) _accurately_ in mm and tell us what it is.

Comment: "As a side question," Asking "side questions" will get your post removed. Start a new question to ask that second question.

Comment: Thanks @DavideAndrea, I've used some calipers to get the pitch between the pins and posted some better (my phone camera sucks for close up macro shots) pictures of the male and female connectors.

edit: using the pitch, and a connector identifier website I _think_ it might be an MTA-100?

Comment: It might be easier to replace or splice the broken part, whatever that is, than to try to build an entire new harness.

Comment: that's a good suggestion @SpehroPefhany.. I just realized I didn't take into account the necessity for a crimp tool to make the connector (assuming I could find what it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the pictures and the pitch. That is a knock-off of [TE's MTA-100](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/3-640440-3/698279). It is not a TE part because the MTA-100 a) is insulation displacement (not crimped) and b) does not have a in-line male plug. I checked other, similar parts from other brands, but none match yours.

This is how I would fix it: get an [MTA-100 PCB header](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/3-641213-3/765858) and solder the cable's wires to its pins, then protect each pin with a short piece of heat shrink tubing.

Better yet, do as @Spehro Pefhany said: fix the present cable.